# How to sum year-to-date if I have null values?

Tags: python, pandas

I sumed the ytd using this code:

```
df['YTD19'] = df['January 19']+df['February 19']+df['March 19']+df['April 19']+df['May 19'] + df['June 19']
df['YTD20'] = df['January 20']+df['February 20']+df['March 20']+df['April 20']+df['May 20'] + df['June 20']
```

But as a result, some rows (especially with null values) did not sum:
[image: output]

Could you please help me how to improve my code?

Comment: You'll have to add a check before you do all of those summations. You'd write it something like 
`if df[January 19'] is not None:
 # summation logic or other if conditions`

Comment: Well it will be a lot of manual work if I check all the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what was the problem:

I forgot to replace null values to zero, that is why it printed bad output. So the only thing needed is:
df.fillna(0)

Answer (score 1):

To improve your code, you can first replace white space with `nan`. Then, to create the YTD19, you can sum all the columns that contain '19' in their name, using `filter(like= ...)` - similar logic applies for YTD2020:

```
# replace empty string and records with only spaces
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

# create your 2 columns
df['YTD19']  = df.filter(like='19').sum(axis=1)
df['YTD20']  = df.filter(like='20').sum(axis=1)
```

```
>>> df[['Manufacturer','Category','Country','YTD19','YTD20']]

  Manufacturer Category   Country  YTD19   YTD20
0            X    Joist     Czech   2910  2677.0
1            Y    Joist    Poland   3269  2366.0
2            Z    Joist  Slovakia   4204  2012.0
```

Comment: thank you, but I have more months in year 2019, so df.filter will not work in this situation :( I have to calculate the sum from january to june

Comment: so for all years, you always want to calculate the sum between January - June?

Comment: Yes, only ytd from january to june

Comment: can you add in your question a real representation of your dataframe? You can use ```df.to_dict()``` to post it. Do you have all months for all years as columns?